# Swift - Is it possible to build the menu bar item outside AppDelegate class in a MacOS ManuBar App?

Tags: macos, swift, menu

I'm doing a lot at once and this is quite overwhelming sometimes. Learning how to build a mac os (with menu bar and a settings window) while learning swift and sometimes trying to adapt objective c tutorials into swift.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.johnmullins.co/blog/2014/08/08/menubar-app/) to help me get started with an app with a menubar. I have made it work, but now I want to improve it a little bit.

All the menu setup in this example is within the AppDelegate class. Since my app has a little more stuff in it, a settings window where I also have to play with tables, I wanted to clean the menu related stuff to a responsible class I called MenuLoader.

I moved all menu building related code from AppDelegate to MenuLoader, and I instantiate MenuLoader on AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

When I run the code though, the app menu bar item appears for what seems the time it is being loaded, with some breaking points I can see clearly that the objects exist and have expected properties, but then the it just disappears. I'm afraid I'm missing some connection the AppDelegate uses to keep a relation of the menu bar referenced.

So my question is: is it possible to have a separate class handling only the status menu bar instead of having a big mess on the AppDelegate?  If you think this might be a matter of my implementation, I'll post some code here, though I'm not sure it will make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible to have a separate class. Moving code into another class doesn't change the functionality as long as your logic is the same.

If something just disappears it's possible that you're not holding a strong reference to that object, and so it gets released as soon as it's out of scope. You might need:

```
 class MyClass {
     var:MyObject! // use this to store the reference to your object

     ...
 }
```

If this doesn't help, please post some of your code.

Comment: Well that was easy and makes total sense. :) Thank you very much. I was only instantiating the new class without keeping any reference to it. Can you please help me with something else: When I'm doing creating a menu item with an action: NSMenuItem(title: name, action: Selector("runMyAction:"), keyEquivalent: "") runMyAction is expected within the AppDelegate class. How can I make it expect the method to be defined in the new class? I would prefer to completely remove the menu logic to this class rather then having to call methods from this action in AppDelegate to the menu loader.

Comment: That all depends on what you set `NSMenuItem`'s `.target` to be -- set it to be whatever object has the runMyAction: method. By the way, you don't need to say Selector("runMyAction:"), just "runMyAction:" will do.

Comment: Thank you and sorry to troubling you. :) I did it: 
var item : NSMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: name, action: "runSublime:", keyEquivalent: "")
item.target = self;
but it still references the AppDelegate one.

Comment: Your code looks fine (and you don't need to say ":NSMenuItem", the compiler will figure it out.) What is `self`... is it the AppDelegate? If not, what makes you say it references the AppDelegate one?

Comment: Ok, I was making changes to the code in the wrong place (I still had the code in AppDelegate as well and was editing that one, silly me :) (I still have to learn about xcode and how to display multiple tabs because going back might just send me to the same class) Everything is now working as I expected! (had to make my class inherit from NSObject not to have methodSignatureForSelector error but it now is perfect. :) Thank you very very much! :)

Comment: Great, glad you fixed it!